# Upgrading Cent OS 6.3 PHP 5.3.3 to 5.3.7 or higher

Tags: php, centos

I need to update PHP to a higher version preferably 5.3.7 or higher on a Cent OS 6.3 box but cannot work out the least disruptive way of doing so.

Could someone run me through this or tell me whether what I need to do is possible?

I originally thought

```
sudo yum upgrade php
```

might work, but I just get this output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum upgrade php
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror01.th.ifl.net
* epel: mirror01.th.ifl.net
* extras: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
* updates: mirror.krystal.co.uk
Setting up Upgrade Process
```

Answer (score 2):

A beter way, is to add the php 55 repo, this way only php is affected and not your other packages.

http://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/rhscl/php55/

To add the repo

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/php55.repo
```

add the following

```
[rhscl-php55]
name=Copr repo for php55 owned by rhscl
baseurl=http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/rhscl/php55/epel-6-$basearch/
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

then install the packages you need

```
yum install php55
```

Answer (score 1):

`rpm -ivh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/remi-release-6-2.el6.remi.noarch.rpm`

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php
```

---

> How would that play with the setup I already have? I have some custom
>   drivers installed for `pdo_dblib` (PDO driver to SQL server)

You can install `php-mssql` instead:

```
Name        : php-mssql
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.4.12
Release     : 1.el6.remi
Size        : 63 k
Repo        : remi
Summary     : MSSQL database module for PHP
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP
Description : The php-mssql package contains a dynamic shared object that will
            : add MSSQL database support to PHP.  It uses the TDS (Tabular
            : DataStream) protocol through the freetds library, hence any
            : database server which supports TDS can be accessed.
```

Comment: How would that play with the setup I already have? I have some custom drivers installed for pdo_dblib (PDO driver to SQL server) etc.

Comment: `php-mssql` can help.

Comment: Thanks. Although I can't see any reason why I can't continue using the PDO driver?

Comment: pdo_dblib is used by the framework i'm using by default

Comment: I guess i'd also need to un-install the currently installed version of php?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS will not provide you a package for this.
The version in CentOS 6 will stay at 5.3.3 and only security updates will be backported to it.

You will need to replace the installed PHP package with a package by a 3rd party.
There are many 3rd party repositories which provide newer PHP versions.
I personally use in such cases the ius repositories.
I prefer it over others (like remi) since they chose not to use conflicting names of packages.

More details can be found here:
http://iuscommunity.org/pages/GettingStarted.html
and here (which is an exmaple of exactly what you are trying to do):
http://iuscommunity.org/pages/IUSClientUsageGuide.html#upgrading-stock-rhel-packages-to-ius-packages

Comment: Huh? IUS _does_ use conflicting names, and thus induces dependency problems.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it does not. The *name* will not be conflicting, the package itself will of course: http://iuscommunity.org/pages/TheSafeRepoInitiative.html

Comment: Funny, they seem to have gotten "safe" entirely backward. The page you linked to summarizes exactly why I never recommend IUS.